# Selecting data from other columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I've rather new at php and mysqli and I've had some success but am currently facing a wall. Mostly because I dont know the terms to express what i'm trying to do.

I can select a row all day long but I seem to be stuck on the same row. I need to be able to select data from further down the column. Here is the code i'm working with.

```
$qry = "select * from products";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);


$getRow = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
$getRowAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);

echo "<img src=\"".$getRow['1'] . "\">";
```

i have several links to images in the picture column on my database but can't seem to figure out a simple way to display the links from other rows in that column. I may be way off base here but I dont think I am. 
this is a layout of the db [db pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMoA6.png)
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only fetches one row, you need to fetch until nothing is left to fetch in a `while` loop.  See examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples which should always be your first stop.

Answer (score 0):

For each mysqli_fetch_assoc you get the result of the next row. As the index starts in -1, the first time you call it, it goes to the first row. So whenever you call it again, it goes to the next row. Use it inside of a loop and you will be all set.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   // $row will have new content each iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc`  Fetch a result row as an associative array, but just 1 row, if you want to get all the result, you have to go through a loop to get everything for the result, example :

```
<?php

  $query = 'SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`';

  $mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost','test','root','password');

  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<img src="' . htmlentities($row['pic']) . '" /><hr />'; 
  }

  unset($row);

  $result->free();

  $mysqli->close();
```

if you want to get all the rows in 1 step for later usage, you would use `mysqli::fetch_all()`, example :

```
<?php

  $query = 'SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`';

  $mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost','test','root','password');

  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  $products = $result->fetch_all();

  $result->free();

  $mysqli->close();

  print_r($products);
```

Comment: thank you this should get me to where i need to be. I got dropped into this database and website with limited exp. i kinda feel like a fishouta water lol.